# Rebus.Defer missing header on Timeout

Tags: ravendb, rebus

I am using Rebus 0.84 and I'm attempting to use the Defer method with a custom header like this.

```
_theBus.AttachHeader(message, "tenant_id", tenantId);
_theBus.Defer(delay, message);
```

But the header does not exist when the 'timeout' happens.  This is my bus configuration.

```
Configure.With(new WindsorContainerAdapter(container))
       .Logging(l => l.Serilog())
       .Transport(t => t.UseMsmqAndGetInputQueueNameFromAppConfig())
       .MessageOwnership(d => d.FromRebusConfigurationSection())
       .Timeouts(t => t.Use(new RavenDbTimeoutStorage(container.Resolve<IDocumentStore>())))
       .Sagas(x => x.Use(new RavenDbSagaPersister(container.Resolve<IDocumentSession>, session => { })))
       .Events(x => x.AddUnitOfWorkManager(new Config.WindsorUnitOfWorkManager(container)))
       .CreateBus()
       .Start()
```

Is that expected behavior?  This is a windows service so am I setting this up properly to be a singleton?

Edit -  <del>I know have a better idea what's happening and I hope that it will lead to a better understanding of Rebus.</del>

The problem is with this line

```
.Sagas(x => x.Use(new RavenDbSagaPersister(container.Resolve<IDocumentSession>, session => { })))
```

In our application we use the tenant_id header to help us connect to the correct database for that message.  If I change the line to use the IDocumentStore that is configured to point to a specific database everything works.  It means my sagas and timeouts are stored in a database that is separate from the actual tenant database.  I can live this this but I'd like to understand why the header does not exist when I use a session retrieved from the container.  I suspect this is due to the timing of the creation of the session for the RavenDbSagaPersister.  Is that correct?

EDIT 2 - Well that was mistaken.  That change still does not work.  Using very similar sampel code but with the default adapter, the timeout headers work great.  I'm going to attempt to isolate the cause by adding the windsor container adapter.  I'll post a link to the code when I can replicate the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds weird - the headers should be included when the deferred message gets delivered, and in fact I've just verified that it works with Rebus 0.84.0.

I do remember though that an earlier version of Rebus had a bug that would not include the headers, but [according to Rebus' changelog](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#0580) that error was removed in version 0.58.0.

So, to answer your questions:

Message headers should definitely be preserved, also when deferring messages.

And yes: The `IBus` instance passed to you from the configuration API should be kept as a singleton instance for the duration of the application lifetime. With Castle Windsor, the container will ensure that it is a singleton, and will also ensure that it is properly disposed when you dispose the container.

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the RavenDB storage?

Comment: the message that ends up in the error queue is actually a  "timeout reply" and it happens almost immediately after I bus.defer.  Could this be something other than my initial assumption?

Comment: sorry, specifically it's Rebus.Messages.TimeoutRequest

Comment: the deferred message is wrapped in a `TimeoutRequest` which does not have the same headers as the wrapped message... it should have a [`rebus-error-message`](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus/blob/master/old/src/Rebus/Shared/Headers.cs#L35-L38) header though, containing the details of why the message failed

Comment: "the deferred message is wrapped in a TimeoutRequest which does not have the same headers as the wrapped message" - Just read this again.  Now I understand the problem.  I was throwing an error whenever the tenant_id was missing but of course since TimeoutRequest doesn't have the same headers of course it was erroring.